# How to find unexisting file in folder?

Tags: windows, batch

I have a folder with .mp4 files which i show online using web application. The rest of information about the video files is taken from a database.

I have *n* files in the database and *n-6* files in my local folder.

How do I find the names of all the missing files in my local folder using the Windows command line?

Comment: I think you need to reword this question, it's difficult to understand. Do you want to list the files which are in your database but not your folder?

Comment: Sorry, yep this is what i want. I can get list of video filenames from database.

Comment: What kind of "database" is this?

Comment: It is MSSQL but i can select just the filenames with "," as delimiter

Comment: some kind of paradox question? :)

Comment: hello, anyone there?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you can get the file names (not with file path) from the database to a TXT file, you have to sort it alphabetically (use OpenOffice Calc or MS Excel - copy and paste TXT conntents to a column in a worksheet page, sort it alphabetically and copy and paste back to a TXT file), you can use that:

1. Start > Execute > cmd
2. Execute that command (where c:\users\eugeneK\desktop\mymusic\ is the path of your local folder):

   ```
   dir /b /on c:\users\eugeneK\desktop\mymusic\ > c:\users\eugeneK\desktop\mymusic\local.txt
   ```
3. Then use (where c:\users\eugeneK\desktop\database.txt is the file list obtained from database and sorted alphabetically):

   ```
   fc /l /c /n c:\users\eugeneK\desktop\database.txt c:\users\eugeneK\desktop\mymusic\local.txt
   ```